# how to end TODO lists in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a list of TODO items, and I'm trying to have 2 TODO lists in the same file, but can't seem to end the first one.

```
FIRST LIST: TODAY
* TODO Item 1
  Description
* TODO Item 2
  Description


SECOND LIST: TOMORROW
* TODO Item 3
  Description
* TODO Item 4 
  Description
```

Unfortunately, `SECOND LIST: TOMORROW` is now part of the description of `TODO Item 2`.  By this, I mean that when I hit shift-tab, I no longer see the text `SECOND LIST: TOMORROW` because it folds under `TODO Item 2`.  What I see is..

```
FIRST LIST: TODAY
* TODO Item 1
* TODO Item 2
* TODO Item 3
* TODO Item 4
```

While what I'd like to see is...

```
FIRST LIST: TODAY
* TODO Item 1
* TODO Item 2


SECOND LIST: TOMORROW
* TODO Item 3
* TODO Item 4
```

How can I escape out of the description mode and start a new, independent list?

**EDIT/UPDATE** I added spaces in between the lists in response to comments.  From [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html), 'A list ends whenever every item has ended, which means before any line less or equally indented than items at top level. It also ends before two blank lines'---From this, I suspect there must be a way to have more than one list in a .org file.  However, in my example, I notice 2 blank lines is not ending the list, but continues on as if a description.

Is this a feature of it being somehow an agenda rather than a plain list?  I know that the following enumerated /does/ end the list on the other hand:

```
FIRST LIST: TODAY
1. Item 1
   Description
2. Item 2
   Description


Second LIST: Tomorrow
1. Item 3
   Description
2. Item 4
   Description
```

I really don't mean any disrespect to you emacs wizards (who amaze me) in that I keep insisting on finding a way to do this, and I understand there's a lot of power to this tool I don't understand yet.  But I would like to have 2 independent non-enumerated todo lists in one .org file, so I can quickly (for me) shuffle unfinished tasks from today to tomorrow without going into depth setting dependencies and due dates.

Comment: how org-mode would know the `FIRST LIST` ends unless you make a new list structure

Comment: Exactly, @kindahero, I'm looking for an end-list delimiter.  Responses below tell me it is impossible, so I'm leaving this open until becomes possible, whether that's a minor mode, or a delimiter, or whatever.

Comment: I'd agree that org-mode needs an end-list delimiter of some kind - it would be useful in many situations where you want to insert a quick sublist, not just at the top level as in your example - it's easy enough to do for indented outlines, and I ran into trouble when converting indented outlines to org-mode for this reason. The best you can do at the moment is add something like * - to indicate returning to the previous level, though it's rather clunky. I imagine the code is all built around the current structure, but I haven't delved into it very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do so within a single file.  Org treats all content under a headline as belonging to it until you reach another headline of the same level.  There is no way to *end* a headline short of starting a new one.

This does have a few shortcomings in that you have to use blank headlines if you want a sub-heading and then to return to the parent level without any new headline.  This means the only text that does not belong to a headline is the text before the first heading, which essentially is the equivalent of an abstract.

The two solutions I can think of would be

1. Use a solution such as the one offered by daramarak
2. Use 2 separate Org files then use the Agenda as a way of keeping track of the multiple TODOs in independent lists that can still be put together to see an overview.

Answer (score 22):

Very simple,  just make the two headers become list items themselves.,  like so:

```
* first todo list. 
** first item in list. 
** second item in list

* second todo list 
** first item and so on...
```

This additionally gives you the ability to fold the lists.

Comment: Thanks, @daramarak.  I thought of that too, but view it more as a work-around.  I'd really like these to be treated as separate lists but in the same document.

Comment: This is just how org-mode or any other outliner works.  If you want to work some other way, then use something else.  This question is a variation of "how do I add text to the parent section after starting a subsectoin?"  The answer is you can't.

Comment: org-mode is a major mode. It treats the whole buffer as one outline. If you need a document with some todo lists in, I would suggest to try to find a more suitable expansion of emacs. There might be a minor mode out there that can give you the functionality you are after.

Comment: @event_jr and daramarak do you have recommendations for something else or minor modes?  It sounds like I've raised hackles here, but I don't feel like I've asked emacs to raise the dead or anything---I am just aiming for two separate lists in one text file.  Multiple independent lists are pretty common things, like on every site. Org-mode was recommended to me as a replacement for personal wiki applications, which have this functionality.

Comment: @Mittenchops I see you're trying to replace HTML with org-mode.  Org-mode is an outliner that can emit HMTL, but the reverse is definitely not true.  Maybe you should try markdown-mode?  Although that would mean you lose all or org-mode's outliner capabilities.  If I were you, I'd convert my workflow from HTML centric to org-mode centric.

Comment: Good advice from event_jr there.  Org-mode is a powerful tool if you learn how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: I see what you guys mean, and I don't doubt that, but I believe it would be much more powerful if I could have 2 lists in the same file. =) That that's not contrary to how it is supposed to be used?  I mean, from the reference manual [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) "A list ends whenever every item has ended, which means before any line less or equally indented than items at top level. It also ends before two blank lines."  With my list above, even when I leave 2 blank lines, it isn't recognizing the end of the list.  However weirdly, it seems to recognize the end of enums.

Comment: @Mittenchops Did you read footnote *1* on the page you linked to?  "*" can only start a list if it has been indented.  So your lists are in fact headlines.

Comment: I'm closing up old threads, but even with footnote 1, it stills states 'it also ends before two blank lines' which should take care of separating the headline from the list.  The list simply isn't ending with 2 blank lines.

Answer (score 8):

Plain lists start with '-' and they end at white-space lines:

```
First list
- Item 1
- Item 2

Second List
- Item 1
- Item 2
```

But TODO's can only be recognized in a headlines (starting with a *). I think this is a part of the org-mode design. You can quickly turn a list into headings by marking the lines and pressing C-c *.
A similar but more light-weight feature to TODO's, ["checkboxes"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html#Checkboxes), can however be used in plain lists for having a list of subtask.

```
List a
- [X] Item 1
- [ ] Item 2

List B
- [ ] Item 1
- [ ] Item 2
```

C-c C-c Toggles a list item. Also lists can be nested and show the satus of their children.

```
- [ ] List A
  - [ ] Item 1
  - [ ] Item 2
- [-] List B
  - [X] Item 1
  - [ ] Item 2
```

Another possibility is using inline tasks C-c C-x t they have a specific ending

```
List 1
*************** TODO Item 1
*************** END

*************** TODO Item 2
*************** END
List 2
*************** TODO Item 1
*************** END
*************** TODO Item 2
*************** END
*************** TODO 
*************** END
```

More discussion can be found [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-11/msg01293.html)