# How to move sub-headings to under other headings in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My list looks like this:

```
* TODAY
** TODO Item 1
** TODO Item 2
* TOMORROW
** TODO Item 3
** TODO Item 4
```

...as a single list, based on some advice I [received here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793428/how-to-end-todo-lists-in-emacs-org-mode). 
I'd like to move TODO Item 2 from under TODAY to under TOMORROW.

The manual [says](http://orgmode.org/org.html):

```
M-up
M-down
Move the item including subitems up/down (swap with previous/next item of same indentation). If the list is ordered, renumbering is automatic.
```

But while I can change the places of Item 1 and Item 2, I cannot move Item 2 outside of the Today heading---I cannot move it down under TOMORROW to precede Item 3.  The buffer tells me:

`cannot move past superior level or buffer limit org mode`

What is the keystroke that lets me move sub-items "past superior level" to under new headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to sanityinc's above, the solution I've adopted is to...

1. Move cursor to *TOMORROW
2. Demote it to ** with M-right
3. Move cursor up to TODO item 2
4. Pull it down beneath **TOMORROW with M-down
5. Return cursor to **TOMORROW and re-promote it with M-left

Constructing a macro for this would probably be better, but it's intuitive and not as bad as it looks.  Still, it would be more convenient if C-M-down or something did this.

Answer (score 22):

You could use <kbd>C-c C-w</kbd> (`org-refile`) and specify the heading where you want to send your TODO item.

As you'll see in this function's documentation (<kbd>C-h f</kbd>`org-refile`), you can customize the `org-refile-targets` and `org-reverse-note-order` variables to determine the list of possible target headings and the position of the moved item within the target heading.

Answer (score 11):

Here are 2 options:

1. Promote Item 2 to the top level with `M-left`, then move it down below "TOMORROW" with `M-down`, and finally demote it under "TOMORROW" with `M-right`.
2. Cut the "Item 2" subtree with `org-cut-special` (`C-c C-x C-w`), then paste it under "TOMORROW" using `org-paste-special` (`C-c C-x C-y`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks @sanityinc.  Yeah, I think (1) is the cleanest way for me to do this.  I ended up working it the other way though.  I demote the heading "Tomorrow" to a subheading with `M-right`, then move it up, `M-up`, then re-promote it `M-left`.  Maybe this warrants another question---I'm an emacs rookie---but is there an easy way to bind `M-right M-up M-left` to a single macro, like `C-M-up`?

Comment: You should read about keyboard macros, which can be saved as functions and bound to keys for future use. It's also trivial to directly write a function which does what you want, but that's beyond the scope of this question or comment.

Answer (score 9):

the simplest way, Just use M-shift-up or M-shift-down you can move item past superior level.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's not (yet?) mentioned in https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Editing.html? Maybe it's a new-ish feature?

Answer (score 2):

I have to do this a lot when making beamer presentations.  The simplest way for me is to just fold then item as you have in your example list and essentially kill and yank the region.  That is, go to the beginning of the `** TODO Item 2` line, set the mark (`C-[SPACE]`), move the point to the beginning of the next line (`C-n`), kill the region (`C-w`), move the point to where you want under the `* Tomorrow` heading, and yank it back (`C-y`).  It is important to get the region rather than just the line (with `C-k`) so that you get all the bits that are folded.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but to expand Mittenchops answers I created the following macro.

```
(defun org-move-subtree-to-next-superior()
  "Moving subtree to next superior."
  (interactive) 
  (org-promote-subtree)
  (org-move-subtree-down)
  (org-demote-subtree))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x t") 'org-move-subtree-to-next-superior)
```