# in EMACS org-mode,How to make some text isn't folded

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Like this:

---

[UNFOLDED TEXT]

```
* Top level headline
** 2nd level
*** 3rd level
       some text
*** 3rd level
       more text

THESE DON'T NEED TO FOLD.
SOME TEXT CONTENT ~~~
```

---

[FOLDED TEXT]

```
* Top level headline...

THESE DON'T NEED TO FOLD.
SOME TEXT CONTENT ~~~
```

---

How to do ? thanks.

Comment: I am afraid there is no such a solution... At least I didn't see it in any documents before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org mode is an outliner -- **content that comes after a header will belong to a header**.

There is no way around this.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793428/how-to-end-todo-lists-in-emacs-org-mode).

You can use:

```
* Top level headline...

* Unfolded headline

THESE DON'T NEED TO FOLD.
SOME TEXT CONTENT ~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct certain subtrees to always open in an unfolded state by using the `:VISIBILITY:` property.