# How do I move text back to just under the parent level

Tags: emacs, org-mode

```
* Parent 

Some text under this level

    ** Headline below parent
    ** Another Headline at the same level
    I don't want this text to be a headline but be indented same as the text under the parent level without being a headline. Cannot do this.
    I just cannot re-indent this text just below the parent level here 

* Another top-level headline
```

Is there any way in org-mode to re-indent plain text back to the same indent level as the plain text just under the parent level but below several headlines under the parent?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
* A Section   
Introductory text.....   
   ** Subsection 1        
   ** Subsection 2    
Further Reading
```

Now, that "Further Reading" is not a headline, I don't want it to be one. However, I cannot "get out of" Subsection 2: Anything I type below it is a part of it. Perhaps I need to structure this some other way such as using lists instead of headlines.

Comment: That some of the text is indented enough to be treated as code makes it hard to understand what you want. Can you give "before" and "after", with both texts formatted as code?

Comment: I corrected the indentation of the question, but I don't understand more what you want. I'm confused: you use `1.` and `2.` which will be treated as lists, not as headlines which are `*`, so I think you're wrong to say `I don't want this text to be a headline` 'cause it isn't.

Comment: Here is the workflow: Create a headline->add some text underneath it->create a headline under the first one below the text you added just prior to this step->another headline at the same level as the last one->now you want to add some text that applies to the top-level headline; however, any text you enter now can only be a part of the last sub-headline. In other words, you cannot enter text at the **end** of the sub-headlines, text that properly belongs to the whole section under the top-level headline.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in org, currently - there is no syntax that ends a subheader to return you to the previous level. But you could add a subsection at the same level - e.g. in your example,

```
* A Section
Introductory text.....
  ** Subsection 1
  Subsection 1 text
  ** Subsection 2
  Subsection 2 text
  ** Further Reading
  Some further reading
```

It might be nice if org had some syntax, like **-, that would end a subsection, but I'm not sure how involved a change that would be - probably pretty extensive.

Comment: I figured as such. I just started using Org a couple of days ago and this is the first thing I hit! Anyways, I've tried this several different ways and so far it has always come down to: anywhere a headline is created, all the text under it becomes a part of that headline and gets indented so. As I am a novice here, I am hoping that there is a solution to this that I am not aware of. I find it hard to believe that this cannot be done. I mean, I know Org is not a typesetting/word-processing program, but still.... Anyways, thanks for your input.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793428/how-to-end-todo-lists-in-emacs-org-mode?rq=1) appears to answer indirectly what I was expecting to get addressed here.